# VueJs login to keycloak with multiple clients

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keycloak

I am trying to set up a **VueJs** application where the user can login with their keycloak user credentials, but when it is done it also logs in to other client in the same realm as well.
I am getting into an **infinite loop**.
I am using **keycloak-js** and so far this is my code:

src/main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import KeycloakPlugin from "./plugins/keycloak";
import { keycloakConfigs, initKeycloak } from "./keycloak";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(KeycloakPlugin);

let keycloakInitialized = false; // Add a flag to track initialization
const authenticatedClients = [];

function initializeKeycloak(config, isFirstClient) {
    const keycloak = initKeycloak(config.clientId);
    const initOptions = isFirstClient
        ? { onLoad: "login-required" }
        : {
              onLoad: "check-sso",
              resource: config.clientId,
          };

    return keycloak
        .init(initOptions)
        .then((authenticated) => {
            if (authenticated) {
                authenticatedClients.push(keycloak);
            }
            return authenticated;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error initializing Keycloak:", error);
            return false; // Return false to indicate failure
        });
}

if (!keycloakInitialized) {
    Promise.all(
        keycloakConfigs.map((config, index) => {
            initializeKeycloak(config, index === 0);
        })
    )
        .then(() => {
            if (authenticatedClients.length > 0) {
                console.log("User is authenticated in at least one client!");
                app.config.globalProperties.$authenticatedClients =
                    authenticatedClients;

                app.mount("#app");

            } else {
                console.log("User is not authenticated in any client!");
                // Handle not authenticated scenario if needed
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error initializing Keycloak:", error);
            // Handle initialization error if needed
        });
    keycloakInitialized = true;
}

console.log(app.config.globalProperties);
```

src/keycloak.js

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const keycloakConfigs = [
    {
        clientId: "vue-client",
        realm: "Test",
        url: "http://localhost:8081",
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/",
    },
    {
        clientId: "vue-client2",
        realm: "Test",
        url: "http://localhost:8081",
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/",
    },
    // Add more client configurations as needed
];

function initKeycloak(clientId) {
    const config = keycloakConfigs.find(
        (config) => config.clientId === clientId
    );
    if (!config) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid clientId: ${clientId}`);
    }

    return new Keycloak(config);
}

export { keycloakConfigs, initKeycloak };
```

src/plugins/keycloak.js

```
import initKeycloak from "@/keycloak";

const keycloakPlugin = {
    install(app) {
        app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak = initKeycloak;
    },
};

export default keycloakPlugin;
```

These are my client configurations. (Same for both just for testing purposes)
[image]

I am getting into an infinite loop and for some reason when I initiate the second login with vue-client2 all cookies stored in http://localhost:8081 gets deleted and the loop continues. Although in keycloak I can see that the user is actually logged in with 2 clients. So it is somewhat working :). Can you please point out what did I do wrong?

Thank you!